# How to Setup an existing postgres DB in a new server?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I have an postgresql DB on an AWS Instance, for some reason the instance now is damaged and the only thing I can do is to detach the disk volume and attach it to a new instance.

The challenge I have now is, how do I setup the postgresql DB I had on the damaged instance volume into the new instance without losing any data.

I tried to attach the damaged instance volume as the main volume in the new instance but it doesnt boot up so what I did was that I mounted the volume as a secondary disk  and now I can see the information in it including the "data" folder where postgres DB information its supposed to be, but I dont know what to do in order to enable the DB on this new instance.

Comment: Could you include a little more information about what exactly you are trying to do, and what your expected / actual results are? What does your setup look like? While the issue may be very clear to you, because you are experiencing it, it's hard to tell what exactly is happening here.

Comment: Normally, a PostgreSQL data directory is self-contained. So copy it to the new system and start PostgreSQL on it.

Answer (score 0):

The files in the `/path/to/data/` directory are all that you need in order for a PostgreSQL instance to start up, given that the permissions are set to `0700` and owned by the user starting up the process (usually `postgres`, but sometimes others).  The other things to bear in mind are:

- Destination OS needs to be the same as where you got the `data/` directory from (because filesystem variations may either corrupt your data or prevent Postgres from starting up)
- Destination filesystem needs to be the same as where you got your `data/` directory from (for reasons similar to above)
- Postgres major version needs to be the same as where you got your `data/` directory from (for reasons similar to above)

If these conditions are met, you should be able to bring up the database and use it.